# Is it possible to extract/reconstitute a MIME attachment from a text only representation of an email?

Tags: python, parsing, mime, email-attachments

I'm writing in python, but this is more of a generic question.

When you go to gmail or similar and you look at an email with an attachment and you click "show original" or some such button you get a huge wall of alphanumerics. My question is: is it possible to take that giant string and turn it back into its original format in python? And if so, how would one go about doing that? I don't necessarily need an answer, just a starting point.

I forgot to add: I'm not allowed to use any already existing email parsers. It's a programming test for getting a job with a programming company. I CAN however look at source code and copy those ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Look at the `email` module, particularly [`email.parser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html).

Comment: Thank you for the starting point! Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use any premade parsing tools. I'm looking for the source code for email.py but can't seem to find it. Am I going about it incorrectly?

Comment: The file is called `parser.py`; it'll be in a folder called `email` in your Python installation's `lib` folder.